# How to draw frame around side captioned figure

Tags: graphics, mdframed, sidecap

I want to draw frame around a side captioned figure. I have created side captioned figure using `sidecap` package and using `\begin{SCfigure} \end{SCfigure}` environment. I have tried `mdframed` package but it is not working. I have also tried `\fbox{}` but frame is coming around graphicx only not around caption. I have googled a lot but could not find out a suitable answer.
The following example works

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{mdframed}
\centering
\includegraphics{image}
\caption{A figure and its caption framed}
\label{fig:test}
\end{mdframed}
\end{figure}
\begin{SCfigure}
\includegraphics{image}
\caption{A figure and its caption framed}
\label{fig:test}
\end{SCfigure}

\end{document}
```

But following example doe snot works

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{mdframed}
\centering
\includegraphics{image}
\caption{A figure and its caption framed}
\label{fig:test}
\end{mdframed}
\end{figure}
\begin{SCfigure}
\begin{mdframed}
\includegraphics{image}
\caption{A figure and its caption framed}
\label{fig:test}
\end{mdframed}
\end{SCfigure}

\end{document}
```

Giving the following error `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \includegraphics`

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: The `boxhandler` package can add these kind of box "wrappers" around traditional figures, but alas not for `sidecap` figures.

Comment: Sorry @mafp I have added MWE now.

Comment: Do you want to draw the frame around Scfigure or around the graphic?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I want to draw frame around SCfigure. I can draw frame around normal figure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are willing to switch to another package, the powerful [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package has a `BOXED` style for these cases:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

{
\floatsetup{style=BOXED,capposition=beside,capbesideposition={top,left}}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{image}
\caption{A figure and its caption framed}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: This is working but problem is it is making all figure in side caption mode. I have only 5 - 6 figure in side caption mode. All other figure should be in traditional figure mode. Is it possible to use `floatrow` package in this case.

Comment: @Apurba Sure it's possible, Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue *is not* related to `mdframed`. It based on an implementation of `sidecap` As the following example shows:

```
\setcounter{errorcontextlines}{999}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidecap}


\begin{document}
\begin{SCfigure}
\begin{itemize}
\item foo
\end{itemize}
\caption{A figure and its caption framed}
\label{fig:test}
\end{SCfigure}
\end{document}
```

The issue is that `sidecap` saves the material inside an `hbox`. So every vertical material like `itemize` or `list` results in an error. To handle such vertical material you have to specify a minipage or a something similar.

---

To work with `mdframed` you have to patch the output command of `sidecap`.

Here an example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{sidefig}{middlelinewidth=2pt,backgroundcolor=lightgray,roundcorner=8pt}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\endSC@FLOAT}{\@FLOAT{\SC@captype}}{\@FLOAT{\SC@captype}\begin{mdframed}[style=sidefig]}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\endSC@FLOAT}{\end@FLOAT}{\end{mdframed}\end@FLOAT}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{SCfigure}
\includegraphics{image}
\caption{A figure and its caption framed}
\label{fig:test}
\end{SCfigure}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: would be nice to have just a little space between figure and caption.  (it looks like the "obvious" approach, adding `\hspace` won't work.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Indeed. Needs to patch some more internals ;-)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: It is an issue with standalone.

Comment: glad it wasn't something more complicated.